# Display transparent image on axes (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, png, grayscale

So I have this transparent image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN8DK.jpg) that I want to display on an axes in MATLAB with its transperancy. To do this, I used the code below, which works with other transparent png images that I have:

```
[A, map, alpha] = imread('fyqslAx.png');
h = imshow(A, map)
set(h, 'AlphaData', alpha);
```

This code however, does not seem to work with the image above. Im guessing this is because it has something to do with the image being grayscale and having a bitdepth of 1, resulting in the map and alpha having nothing in it (whereas the other png transparent images I have, have something in map and alpha). If I just use this:

```
A = imread('fyqslAx.png');
h = imshow(A)
```

A black background appears where the image should be transparent.

How do I display this https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN8DK.jpg with its transperancy on an axes?

EDIT: horchler's method worked; Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `imfinfo('fyqslAx.png')`, you'll see that the `'Transparency'` is specified as `'simple'` and the `'SimpleTransparencyData'` is set to `0` (`false`). I can't find documentation on this, but I think that this may indicate that the alpha channel has been compressed into the image data because the the image is binary and grayscale. Effectively the image is a binary mask, either transparent or not. You can display your image like this:

```
A = imread('fyqslAx.png');
h = imshow(A);
set(h, 'AlphaData', A);
```

If you try to return a colormap and/or alpha channel from `imread` using extra output arguments, you'll see that both are empty.